# Convert any mesh to quads to fix shading issues

Tags: mesh, shaders

I have made some meshes in Blender for a game I'm working on.
Here's an image of it.
[image: Shading issue]

You can see the shading is terrible, so I was thinking about converting this mesh to quads. But how can I do that (in a way it's doesn't become more than ~10,000 tris?

Comment: Hi There, could you please embed the image in your post? You can use the [Edit] link and the "Add Image" button. Also, what have you tried so far? Remesh modifier?

Comment: I have tried Grid Fill, but that didn't turn out good at all. And remesh didn't work for me either.

Comment: I'd take a look at ways to retopology. There are some addons that will try to do it automatically.

Comment: Your objects shapes are pretty complex and uneven so I doubt you'll find any good automated way  to do this.